# Left Join return no rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Why does this SQL query return no rows ?

```
select CMV.CLIENT_CMF,IWZ.NATIONALITY 
from  MBTC_DEV_CLIENT_MAST_VIEW CMV 
left join iwz_nationality IWZ on UPPER(CMV.NATIONALITY) = UPPER(IWZ.NATIONALITY)
where IWZ.NATIONALITY is not null;
```

I have to get clients nationality that's in the `Nationality` table

Comment: In your question, can you pick a nationality in the `MBTC_DEV_CLIENT_MAST_VIEW` view and discuss how you see it in the `iwz_nationality` table?  As an example, what about an instance of the United Kingdom? It is apparent from the UPPER function that I would not expect a foreign key constraints on the view's underlying objects which make up its `nationality` column.

Comment: For example. in _MBTC_DEV_CLIENT_MAST_VIEW_ client "Marshall Matters" nationality is "American" the code must check if "American" is in _iwz_nationality_. but in my code NATIONALITY returns null to all rows

Comment: @Jakey In oracle left outer join will not return back any rows only if table mentioned on the left of left outer join condition has no rows. In your case that table is "MBTC_DEV_CLIENT_MAST_VIEW".  Please check if this table has data or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your current `WHERE` clause is filtering off records having `NULL` nationality.  Move that logic to the `ON` clause of the join and you should get the behavior you expect:

```sql
SELECT
    CMV.CLIENT_CMF,
    IWZ.NATIONALITY
FROM MBTC_DEV_CLIENT_MAST_VIEW CMV
LEFT JOIN iwz_nationality IWZ
    ON UPPER(CMV.NATIONALITY) = UPPER(IWZ.NATIONALITY) AND
       IWZ.NATIONALITY IS NOT NULL;
```

Actually, your current query is logically identical to doing an *inner* join between the two tables.  The above version will behave like a left join.

Comment: the problem here is IWZ.NATIONALITY returns null. but if you check manually majority of nationality in MBTC_DEV_CLIENT_MAST_VIEW is in iwz_nationality

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
select CMV.CLIENT_CMF,IWZ.NATIONALITY 
from  MBTC_DEV_CLIENT_MAST_VIEW CMV left join
      iwz_nationality IWZ
      on UPPER(CMV.NATIONALITY) = UPPER(IWZ.NATIONALITY)
where IWZ.NATIONALITY is not null;
```

returns no rows because no rows in the two tables match the condition `UPPER(CMV.NATIONALITY) = UPPER(IWZ.NATIONALITY)`.

If you want only matches, then use `JOIN`, not `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select CMV.CLIENT_CMF, IWZ.NATIONALITY 
from  MBTC_DEV_CLIENT_MAST_VIEW CMV join
      iwz_nationality IWZ
      on UPPER(CMV.NATIONALITY) = UPPER(IWZ.NATIONALITY);
```

However, this will also return no rows.  You have a *data* problem and have not provided any information on how to solve it.  My guess is that it is obvious why the values do not match (say they are `NULL` in one table or one table uses a prefix).  However, there can be more subtle reasons, such as spaces or look-alike characters.